# Virtualizing ListBox ContextMenu XamlParseException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have WPF(.NET 4.5) client app with a huge list of items in virtualizing `ListBox`. Every `ListBoxItem` have `ContextMenu` with some actions.

Some client's are receiving unhandled exceptions when opening that `ContextMenu`. Almost 100% repro on some PC's with Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 on board.

`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` message:

> Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.Header' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.

**NOTE:** I've tried to add `x:Shared="False"` - not a fix of that problem

Huge Exception StackTrace:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.Header' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
at System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedItemsControl.OnHeaderChanged(Object oldHeader, Object newHeader)
at System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedItemsControl.OnHeaderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List'1 affectedChildren, UncommonField'1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List'1 affectedChildren)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField'1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField'1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator& generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider, IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem, Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean& computedAreContainersUniformlySized, IList& items, Object& item, IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport, VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit& cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double& firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size& stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize, Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean& mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure, Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean& hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean& hasVirtualizingChildren)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable'1& lastPageSafeOffset, List'1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable'1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean remeasure)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

--Inner Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)
at System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedItemsControl.OnHeaderChanged(Object oldHeader, Object newHeader)
at System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedItemsControl.OnHeaderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
```

`ContextMenu` resource (in `UserControl.Resources` tag):

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="QuestionContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddChildCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding Model}"
              Header="{StaticResource s_Question_Tooltip_AddChildAnswer}" />
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding Model}"
              Header="{StaticResource s_Remove}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

`DataTemplate` resource (in `UserControl.Resources` tag):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dt_Questions"
              DataType="secure:QuestionViewModel">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid"
          Width="{Binding ElementName=lvQuestions, Path=ActualWidth}"
          MinHeight="22"
          ContextMenu="{StaticResource QuestionContextMenu}"
          Margin="0 2 0 2">
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

`ListBox` in Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lvQuestions"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         Padding="0 2 0 20"
         Panel.ZIndex="{Binding QuestionsZindex}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dt_Questions}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionsView, Mode=OneWay}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuestionViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         Style="{StaticResource LeftListBox}"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

`ListBox` Style with Template:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VirtualizingItemsPanelTemplate">
    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
<Style x:Key="LeftListBox"
        TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource VirtualizingItemsPanelTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <ScrollViewer Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                            CanContentScroll="True"
                                            Style="{StaticResource LeftScrollViewerStyle}">
                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`ListBoxItem` Template:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My thoughts: I'm using `ContextMenu` wrong, or it's a problem with `ScrollUnit="Pixel"` in .NET 4.5.

PS: I've spent a lot of time to identify that issue source is `ContextMenu`. I've tried to remake somehow my XAML markup to fix that issue... Issue still appearing. I don't want to disable virtualization or make my own `ContextMenu` control. I want to find a workaround for that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer:

The source of the exception was not a `ContextMenu`, it was `MenuItem` with `Header` roperty set as `StaticResource` to my localization value.
This value resource was a `TextBlock`, not a `String`.

was:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="s_Question_Tooltip_AddChildAnswer">
    Add answer to this question
<TextBlock>
```

fix:

```
<s:String x:Key="s_Question_Tooltip_AddChildAnswer">
    Add answer to this question
</s:String>
```